# Choose support for polynomial interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

I have the following table, where $t$ is defined in minutes and $v(t)$ in $m / s$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
t& 0 & 0.5 & 1 & 1.5 & 2 & 2.5 & 3 \\ \hline
v(t) & 100  & 160 & 135 & 100 & 120 & 95 & 115\\ \hline
\end{array}

the question is:

> What supports would you take to control the behavior at 45 seconds (t = 0.75)?

I think that the following supports should be taken but I do not know if I am right:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
t& 0 & 0.5 & 1 & 1.5 \\ \hline
v(t) & 100  & 160 & 135 & 100\\ \hline
\end{array}

Does the runge effect affect this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by supports?

Comment: @Moo each t and his v(t) of the table.